# Enter-PSSession is not working in my Powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

When I run the lines below from a script the file ends up being created on my local machine.

```
$cred = Get-Credential domain\DanTest
Enter-PSSession -computerName xsappb01 -credential $cred

New-Item -type file c:\temp\blahxsappk02.txt

exit-pssession
```

When I run each line individually from the powershell console the remote session is created correctly and the file is created on the remote machine.  Any thoughts on why?  Is it a timing issue is the script perhaps?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Not sure if it is a timing issue.  I suspect it's more like Enter-PSSession is invoking something like a nested prompt and your subsequent commands are not executing within it.  Anyway, I believe Enter/Exit-PSSession is meant for interactive use - not scripting use.  For scripts use New-PSSession and pass that session instance into Invoke-Command e.g.:

```
$cred = Get-Credential domain\DanTest 
$s = New-PSSession -computerName xsappb01 -credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock {New-Item -type file c:\temp\blah.txt}
Remove-PSSession $s
```

Comment: Thanks Keith - I will give this a look tomorrow when I get back to the office.

Comment: That appears to do the trick.  One thing is the last line needs to be Remove-PSSession $s

Comment: @DanSnell Remove-PSSession always is required when I use New-PSSession and Invoke-Command -Session ?

Comment: Worth adding: in order to access variables declared before the `Invoke-Command`, you need to use the `-ArgumentList` parameter