# Remote Registry using Enter-PSSession

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to read strings in a remote registry. When I run the script I am working on, it connects to the workstation in the list, but it only reads the local computer when running, not the remote. any Ideas?

```
#create open dialog box
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{
    [void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( 'System.Windows.Forms' );
    $d = New-Object Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;
    $d.ShowHelp = $True;
    $d.filter = "Comma Separated Value (*.csv)| *.csv";
    $d.ShowDialog( ) | Out-Null;
    $d.filename;
}

# Set Variables with arguments
$strFile = Get-FileName;
$strComputer = Get-Content $strFile;
$date = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy";
$outputFile = "C:\PowerShell\Reports";

$cred = Get-Credential

foreach($computer in $strComputer)
{
Enter-PSSession $computer -Credential $cred
Set-Location HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Reliability
$systemInfo = Get-Item -Name LastComputerName
Write-Host $systemInfo
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PSSession is not working in my Powershell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705321/pssession-is-not-working-in-my-powershell-script)

Comment: Enter-PSSession can only be used this way in an interactive prompt, not from a script

Comment: I would use WMI instead, although PSSession seems easy, it performs inconsistently for me on our domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($computer in $strComputer)
{
Enter-PSSession $computer -Credential $cred
..
..
}
```

The above code won't work. `Enter-PSSession` is not for using in a script. Anything written after that in a script won't run.

Instead, use `Invoke-Command` and pass rest of the script block as a parameter value. For example,

```
foreach ($computer in $strComputer) {
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
      Set-Location HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Reliability
      $systemInfo = Get-Item -Name LastComputerName
      Write-Host $systemInfo
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the comments already explained, `Enter-PSSession` is for interactive use. To read remote registry entries, there are several ways.

Use plain `reg.exe`, it works well enough. Like so,

```
foreach($computer in $strComputers) {
  reg query \\$computer\hklm\software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Reliability  /v LastComputerName
}
```

Use PSSessions. Create a session and `Invoke-Command` to read registry. Like so,

```
function GetRegistryValues {
  param($rpath, $ivalue)
  Set-Location $rpath
  $systemInfo = (Get-ItemProperty .).$ivalue
  Write-Host $systemInfo
}
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer
Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock ${function:GetRegistryValues} `
 -argumentlist "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Reliability",`
 "LastComputerName"
Remove-PSSession $session
```

Use .Net classes, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey. Like so,

```
$sk = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, $server)
$k = $sk.opensubkey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Reliability", $false)
write-host $k.getvalue("LastComputerName")
```