# Enter-PSSession not returning variables

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to enter in every computer in a list I have and remove a software from it.

When I try the code (not using foreach), the code works fine. But when I try to loop it, it doesnt work at all.

Where there is "do something", it doesn't do anything. For instance, I tried to do:

```
$product = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.name -like "7-zip*"}
```

and in the next line, print on screen the `$product` variable. But it's always empty.

When I manually enter a `pssession` and run this command, it returns me something.

What I'm doing wrong here? I already wasted hours trying to figure this out, but no luck :(

```
foreach ($computer in $computers){

    if(Test-Connection "$computer" -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){

        Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $computer

        "do something"

        Exit-PSSession

    }else{

        Write-Warning "computer is offline."

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705321/enter-pssession-is-not-working-in-my-powershell-script - `Enter-PSSession` is not meant to be used in scripts. It's for interactive use only.

Answer (score 1):

Use invoke-command
Example:

```
$ReturnValue = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock{
    #DoSomethingHere
}
Write-host $Returnvalue #Will print the output of the scriptblock
```

Comment: Ah, thats great! It worked now! Thank you very much!